# Trailing stop order of IBrokers in R

Tags: r, interactive-brokers, ibrokers

Here is a condition that I want place a TRAIL order with stop price is 43.41 and  trailing Percent is 2%.

I use IBrokers.zip of joshuaulrich from github.

However, when I place TRAIL order with trailing Percent, the order is not contained with trailing Percent.

Here is my code,

```
twsOrder(action = "SELL", totalQuantity = 399, orderType = "TRAIL",trailingPercent = "2", tif = "GTC", transmit = FALSE, trailStopPrice = 43.41)
```

[the picture that i want to place order on IB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxhbF.png)

What am I missing? And how can I solve the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing that a better place to ask would be the support services at IBrokers: https://tidelift.com/subscription/pkg/cran-ibrokers?utm_source=cran-ibrokers&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=readme

Comment: when you asked joshuaulrich, what did he say?

Comment: Not yet replied